# Is possible to disable update button from CButtonColumn for first two values in Yii

Tags: yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

In my Yii web application, I want to disable update link for first two values in CButtonColumn. How to resolve this. My Cgridview is,
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: do you mean the disabling the `CButtonColumn` buttons for the first two rows in a `CGridView`?

Comment: yes. I want to disable edit button for the first two rows in   CGridView

Comment: how about after filtering the `CGridView`, or if the grid is in page 2, should the buttons of the first two rows of the resulting data be still disabled?

Comment: @Jencen, Actually, in my cgridview having five rows only. In that first two rows are predefined, So I want to disable edit button for that two entries and remaining three entries should make editable. How to possible that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, You can use `"visible"` attribute for this button in your `CButtonColumn` and pass a PHP expression (within single quotes) to control when it gets shown and when it doesn't:

For example, the object having attribute "name" equal to `"Full-Time Contract"` not be shown.

```
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{update} {view}',
    'buttons'=>array(
           'update'=>array(
                    'visible'=>'($data->name !== "Full-Time Contract")'
            ),
     ),
)
```

You can adapt it according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

So you can use Asfi's answer, which is Yii's way to solve this. But if you want something more simple and more general in disabling the first two rows of the table, whatever the values are, then I suggest just do it via jQuery, which is by default supported by Yii.

```
$('table tr:first-child button,table tr:eq(2) button').prop('disabled',true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ncnm1jme/